# Query to select Items with one-to-many associations

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, inner-join

I have a table with data as below.

```
Name   Product
Ram    Acer
Indu   Sony
Indu   Acer
Rahul  Sony
Divya  Acer
Divya  Dell
```

Now I want the query which selects the name that has both Acer and Sony product.

The result should be just `Indu`.

Comment: i don't know why there is answer's for these kind of question.i Called this spoon feeding

Comment: your welcome buddy .but its not personal

Comment: you know what, I am sorry. I shouldn't have taken it personal either..

Answer (score 2):

```
select Name 
from your_table 
where Product in ('Acer', 'Sony')
group by Name
having count(Product) > 1
```

If you are looking for even more Products at the same time, then you have to increase the number in your count:

```
where Product in ('Acer', 'Sony', 'Dell')
...
having count(Product) > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This will select all the names that have products **BOTH** in `ACER` and `SONY`

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM tableName
WHERE Product = 'Acer' AND
      Name IN (SELECT Name 
                 FROM tableName 
                 WHERE Product = 'Sony')
```

Comment: That is giving more results that the OP wants: Ram. Divya, Indu, Rahul.

Comment: Hi John, Probably you misunderstood the question.. I want the query to select guys who bought both Acer and Sony. Your current query gives the results for whoever bought Sony or Acer... Correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: @juergend that's why I updated the answer.

Comment: @user1087661 try my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks John for your effort to help me :) ..